# Is it possible to have a read replicas of azure flexible postgresql server with a subset of data?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to replicate a specific subset of data (certain schema,dbs') to a readonly copy of Azure postgres flexible server.  Thanks Brian

Comment: maybe you need to analyze Logical Replication https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html

Comment: Thank you will try this out-Cheers

Comment: @bOd did you get it ?

Comment: @bOd Can you please update if you were able to achieve this

Comment: @bOd, Karthik could you advise if you found any solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Logical replication and logical decoding in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-logical#limitations)

> **Limitations**
>
> Read replicas - Azure Database for PostgreSQL read replicas are not
> currently supported with flexible servers.

Comment: That note has been [removed](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/1dd35abcf9a1bb6c0698394b3d4fea29d81a08c6#diff-dae26986fc187423dd0db8b101d85850d2fe5a327aea8c1143fff60605216d3dL244) from the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Read Replica feature will be available in Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible server around 6/30/22 in private preview and subsequently in public preview in Q3 quarter.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment this is not possible with azure so we ended up using pglogical replication to copy specific databases over between the regions.